# how to call spring controller in jquery ajax success method

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have created a spring controller and a jsp page. In jsp page I am using jquery ajax call to hit the controller. Now, this controller returns a json response as string. Now on based of json response in success method, I want to call a next controller call which will return a ModelAndView jsp page. How can I do this. Below is my code:

JSP Jquery ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
         var formData = getFormData();
         if(formData!=false){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            'url': 'http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/fieldMappingNext.htm',
            data: {jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){ 
                 try{
                    var strResponse=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                }catch(err){}
                if(response.status=='ok')
                {
                    alert ("okokokokokokokokok");
                //I am successfully reaching till here. 
                //But in case of this alert box I want to call a 
                //controller which will return ModelAndView and 
                //should open a corresponding ModelAndView jsp page.
                //something like:
                /*
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', 
                'url': 'http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/abcxyz.htm',  
                )};
                */
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("ERROR!!");
                } 

            },
            timeout: 10000,
            error: function(xhr, status, err){ 
                if(response.status=='timeout')
                {   
                    alert('Request time has been out','');
                }
                console.log(status,err); 
            }
        }); }
     });
});
```

Controller class methods:

```
@RequestMapping (value="fieldMappingNext.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody String addFieldMappingNext(@RequestParam String jsonData)
{
    String customerID =null;
    String objectID = null;
    String syncFieldName = null;
    String optMapping = null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
    try{
        JSONObject requestedJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        customerID = requestedJSONObject.getString("customerID");
        objectID = requestedJSONObject.getString("objectID");
        syncFieldName = requestedJSONObject.getString("syncFieldName");
        optMapping = requestedJSONObject.getString("optMapping");
    }catch(Exception exex){
        exex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(optMapping.equalsIgnoreCase("direct")){
        long metadataID=rwCustomerService.getMetaDataID(customerID,objectID);
        List<RWFieldDetail> list=rwCustomerService.getFieldDetailNames(metadataID);
        request.setAttribute("customerID", customerID);
        request.setAttribute("objectID", objectID);
        request.setAttribute("optMapping", optMapping);
        request.setAttribute("syncFieldName", syncFieldName);
        request.setAttribute("fieldNames", list);
        try {
            jsonResponse.put("status", "ok");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse.toString();
}
```

Second Controller method that I want to call from jquery success method:

```
@RequestMapping (value="abcxyz.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
ModelAndView fieldMapping(){
ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("FieldMappingMainScreenNext");
return modelAndView;
}
```

How do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the second handler method returns `ModelAndView`, you should redirect from the success callback:

```
...

success: function(response) {
    window.location.replace(response.url);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code you can use something like:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
if(condition1){
   map.put("url","url1.html");
}
if(condition2){
   map.put("url","url2.html");
}
```

Convert it to a JSON string and revert it back. Afterwards, in the jquery portion you'll get the response:

```
success:function(jsonStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    var url = obj.url;
}
```

That is how you can get the url. If you want to load an other page or create an ajax call then you can do it.